# AngularJS Changing menu's inside ng-switch-when

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can i put an anchor tag (`<a>`) inside a ng-switch-when?
Here is my code: [( HERE IS A PREVIEW PLNKR LINK)](http://plnkr.co/edit/pv2o9j3ywJI4RRZMGOFT?p=preview)
i want to do something like this:

```
<div ng-switch-when="Jquery">
    <h3>Jquery</h3>

    <a class="col-md-1 menu" ng-class="{active: tab == 'Angular'}" ng-click="tab='Angular'"><b>Angular</b></a>

    <br /> jQuery is a cross-platform JavaScript library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML. jQuery is the most popular JavaScript library in use today, with installation on 65% of the top 10 million highest-trafficked sites on the
    Web. jQuery is free, open-source software licensed under the MIT License.
</div>
```

Here i have 3 menus, and on second menu (JQUERY), I put a link to menu 1 (ANGULAR), but it does not work... Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-switch creates a new scope... you need to use $parent to access the correct scope to define the tab attribute:

```
<a class="col-md-1 menu" ng-click="$parent.tab='Angular'"><b>Angular</b></a>
```

(I removed the class because it was unnecessary here)

Comment: Thanks a lot! you're my hero !!